# How to create a test that passes when a function is triggered?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, mocking, xctest

I am trying to unit test a two functions in a view controller class. The two functions will create a user and sign in a user respectively. My tests are not UI related.

As of now, I simply need to create a test that passes when one of the functions is called. The goal is to do this without changing the current view controller implementation if possible and just keep it all in the testing class/function.

How do I go about this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As curious as I am to learn about latest mocking tools (I still mock by hand), SO isn't a forum for opinion-based questions. That's why you'll see the negative score, and the question eventually being closed. …Instead, SO focuses on specific programming problems, and solutions to those problems.

Comment: Alrighty then, sorry! Will restructure question appropriately.

Comment: @JonReid Alright, just edited it to make it a specific programming problem! If it's still not fit for SO, let me know and I will edit it again!

Comment: I take back what I said about "the question eventually being closed" — well done.

Comment: Are you looking for one test that verifies "create user" is called, and another test to verify "sign in user"?

Comment: @JonReid Exactly!

Comment: @JonReid So I watched your presentation about testing at try! Swift Tokyo 2017 and was wondering if that's how we should test VC's too. If so, then does that mean I'll create a protocol, make the VC conform to that protocol, create a "fake" VC for testing, and then basically rewrite all the functions from the original VC with the addition of asserts/matches/etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming a view controller with a method that invokes either "create user" or "sign in user". (You say it's not UI related, but we can easily test button taps if that's the trigger.)

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    func triggeringMethod() {
        // Calls one of the two methods below
    }

    func createUser() {
        // Does stuff
    }

    func signInUser() {
        // Does stuff
    }
}
```

And it sounds like you want to test the flow, but not the effect. That is, you want to test "Was `createUser()` called?" There are several ways to get what you want, but the better ways will require you to change your view controller implementation.

## Making a Partial Mock

A standard trick from *Working Effectively With Legacy Code* by Michael Feathers is "Subclass and Override Method". Let's start there. In test code, we can make

```
class TestableMyViewController: MyViewController {
    override func createUser() {
    }

    override func signInUser() {
    }
}
```

So far, this is a way of stubbing out the effects of these methods. But we can now add the mocking techniques from my try! Swift Tokyo talk.

```
class TestableMyViewController: MyViewController {
    var createUserCallCount = 0
    var signInUserCallCount = 0

    override func createUser() {
        createUserCallCount += 1
    }

    override func signInUser() {
        signInUserCallCount += 1
    }
}
```

Now you can call the triggering method, and check the call counts.

(Changes you may have to make: The class can't be `final`. The methods can't be `private`.)

## Moving the Workers

While this is a fine place to start, don't stop there. What we've created is a "partial mock". That's where we've kept most of the functionality, but mocked out a couple of the methods. This is something to avoid. The reason is that we end up with class that mixes production code and test code. It would be far too easy to end up in a situation where you're inadvertently testing test code instead of testing production code.

What the partial mock makes clear is that we're missing a boundary. The view controller is doing too much. The actual work of "create user" and "sign in user" should be performed by another type (possibly even 2 types). In Swift, we can define this boundary with a protocol. That way production code can use the real functionality, while for test code we can inject mocks.

This means the production code should avoid deciding for itself who does the actual work. Instead, we should *tell* it who does the work. That way, tests can provide alternative workers. Specifying these dependencies from the outside is called "Dependency Injection".

## Passing Back Effects

Another option lets us avoid mocks altogether. Instead of testing whether something was called, we can describe the desired effect in an enumeration. Then we can define effects like

```
enum Effect {
    case createUser(CreateUserRequestModel)
    case signInUser(SignInUserRequestModel)
}
```

Instead of the triggering method calling `createUser()` or `signInUser()`, it would call a delegate. (Another option is to pass in closures instead of specifying delegates.)

```
protocol Delegate {
    perform(_ effect: Effect)
}
```

Then in the triggering method,

```
delegate?.perform(.createUser(parameters))
```

This means it's up to the actual delegate to transform these enumeration values into actual work. But it makes the tests easy to write. All we need is to provide a testing implementation that captures the `Effect` value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I’ll try this when I get home!

Comment: I understand and thank you again! I did have one followup question though: so in the future, when designing a signup function, I should have a model User and that model should have a signup member function. Then in my view controller's sign up function, I should pass it a User object and then call that object's signup member function? This way I use dependency injection + I can use the protocol pattern to test, is that all correct?

Comment: Yes. I would actually take it a step further and separate the "User" model from "network requests that work on User objects". In other words, I would treat User as the data to pass around, and little more than that. It can serve as a Request Model, which I've described here: https://qualitycoding.org/request-model/

Comment: I see. Alright, awesome thank you! Very helpful answers.

Comment: Quick question (and let me know if I should convert this into an official SO question): If we have a bunch of legacy code that has a bunch of models, but instead of member functions all the functions are in view controllers (so to use dependency injection we would have to refactor a lot of our codebase), which method of testing should we use? Should we refactor and use mocking with dependency injection?

Comment: That does sound like it might be good as a separate question :)

Comment: I made it, would really like to see you answer it when convenient! https://stackoverflow.com/q/53662302/9044237